# Does "That is how I've always used it." make sense?

Tags: phrase-usage

"That is how I've always used it"

Does it make sense? Does it sound natural? Is there any other way of saying it? Answers will be appreciated. :)

(clarification: There's a body soap that is not supposed to be used as shampoo, but I've have done it all the time regardless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Absolutely natural. Slightly more common would be "that's how I've always done it", which has usage beyond things that are 'used'. Also, contracting "that is" to "that's" would be more natural in every dialect I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

That works. I'm a native English speaker, and I've said that sentence on multiple occasions.

> I've always done it that way.

I've heard this version moderately often, and I've used it a few times. It's a little more generic.

> I've always used it that way.

If you don't want more generic, this is the `used` version of my first alternate example.

There are a lot of ways this could be said that would still be natural.

Going off-topic, while there are some shampoos that are designed specifically for hair, there really isn't a lot of difference conceptually from soap and shampoo. Humans are hairy enough in general that I don't think a soap that didn't plausibly work as a shampoo would be very popular hand soap.

Comment: Running with the off-topic for a second, I believe the bigger difference is in the nature of the dirt being removed than in the surface it's being removed from. But household soaps suitable for use on people existing before any that were made especially for hair.